# Static Qt program build in VS2013 - a lot of unresolved externals

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, linker

#### After nights trying to build Qt properly at last I made it with:

`configure -static -debug-and-release -developer-build -mp -opengl desktop -platform win32-msvc2013 -no-webkit -qt-zlib`

and

`/MT, MTd` flags in mkspecs\win32-msvc2013\qmake.conf 
but it did not help me much.

I am using VS2013 Pro, with QT Add-in 1.2.3, and when I tried to compile add-in template I received 55 unresolved external errors, most of them was from OpenGL, so I added opengl32.lib to linker, and error number reduced to 42, but still most of them are from OpenGL. Libs like GLU32 or Qt5OpenGL did not helped me at all.

#### Here are few unresolved external symbols errors from linker:

```
_WSAAsyncSelect@16 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall QEventDispatcherWin32::createInternalHwnd(void)" (?createInternalHwnd@QEventDispatcherWin32@@AAEXXZ)
_glBindBuffer@8 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall QOpenGLBuffer::bind(void)" (?bind@QOpenGLBuffer@@QAE_NXZ)
_glCompileShader@4 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall QOpenGLShaderPrivate::compile(class QOpenGLShader *)" (?compile@QOpenGLShaderPrivate@@QAE_NPAVQOpenGLShader@@@Z)
_glUniform4fv@12 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall QOpenGLFunctions::glUniform4fv(int,int,float const *)" (?glUniform4fv@QOpenGLFunctions@@QAEXHHPBM@Z)
```

#### And for me its quite strange, cos those errors are from core gl lib, which is linked :

```
qtmain.lib
Qt5Core.lib
Qt5Gui.lib
Qt5Widgets.lib
opengl32.lib
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell us which Qt version have you downloaded from the [Qt website](http://qt-project.org/downloads)?

Also, you have to be careful because Qt is not bundle with openGL by default, you have to download the proper version (the one with openGL in the name obviously)

Hope it helps!

Comment: It Was Qt 5.3.0 for Windows x64 VS 2013 OpenGL. I figured it out propobably. I have OpenGL 1.0(?) but in QT is higher version, and my OGL have luck of few functions,which cause errors. So... how to include higher version of OGL? (or build?) I need .lib files, but what i know versions >1.0 are just in headers (glew ex.), but when i added them, nothing changed.

Comment: I don't understand how you can have only OGL 1.0 even if you have install Qt 5.3.0 with OGL include in it... I have try to reproduce your error but can't find a way to have only openGL version 1.0 on my machine.
I will have a look ASAP on another computer.

Comment: What's your graphic card?

Comment: From the manufacturer website: [GTX 550Ti](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-550ti/specifications)
Your graphic card support up to the 4.2 version...
Please re-install your graphic card driver, might be the issue here. [Driver DL page](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/77837)

Comment: I thing it have nothing to do with card, it looks like compiler cant recognize libs in system.

Comment: Have you try compiling a Qt openGL sample using an untouched Qt (not the one that you've compiled, but one download from their website)?

Comment: The problem is i didnt use OpenGl in my project at all ;/ It looks like this QT version it to render whole window,beacouse i dont see any other need to include it in this project.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out the following libraries:

`imm32.lib
winmm.lib
Ws2_32.lib
qtharfbuzzng.lib`

This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27807379/4415923